# Is there a way to hide/get rid of indented space on sublime text?

Tags: formatting, editor, sublimetext2, indentation

When I'm working on a large project sometimes the layer of code gets very deep so it ends up like I've shown in the image.

[image]

I have tried deselecting the "Word Wrap" which is not what I'm looking for since it goes all the way across. I want certain word wrapping in my file but deselecting and setting "Word Wrap Column" didn't help.

Is there any other way to do this cause I see lot of spaces that's just wasted on my screen with this setup.

Comment: Maybe you could reduce the tab size? I set mine to use two spaces instead of a tab, and I have loads more room now.

Comment: If only. I work on a team and different people have their own settings. I don't want to cause massive conflicts on all the files. :P

Comment: Have you tried `reindent`?

Comment: @AGS That helps somewhat.

Comment: Cool, what does it now look like?

Comment: Not a lot of difference but it's cleaner than the indentation that I'm used to (Vintage mode - gg+= ).